# Batch Code to Skip Script if File is too Old

Tags: date, batch-file, last-modified

### My Problem

As there are a ton of threads that address 'using a batch file to return file modify date' (or delete files older than, etc) - let me first specify my issue.

I'm looking to create a **batch** (not PowerShell, etc) that will return the last modify date of a specific file given **UNC** path and filename.

### Code, Attempt 1

I've taken a peek at a few potential solutions on other threads, but I've run into a number of unique issues. The first and most obvious solution for this would be the "ForFiles" command in batch. For example:

```
set myPath=\\myUNCpath
set myFile=myFileName.csv

forfiles /p "%myPath%" /m %myFile% /c "GoTo OldFile" /d -6
```

Thus, if the file is older than I want -- jump to a specific section of my batch for that. However, this yields the error:

> ERROR: UNC paths (\machine\share) are not supported.

However, this cmd won't work due to the use of UNC (which is critical as this batch is called by system's task scheduler). So it seems like the 'ForFiles' cmd is out.

### Code, Attempt 2

I could go a more round about way of doing it, but simply retrieving the last modified date of the file (which in batch would return a string).  I can truncate the string to the necessary date values, convert to a date, and then compare to current date. To do that, I've also looked into just using a for loop such as:

```
set myFile=\\myUNCpath\myFileName.csv
echo %myFile%
pause

FOR %%f IN (%myFile%) DO SET myFileDate=%%~tf
echo %myFileDate%
pause
```

Though my first debug echo provides the proper full file name, my second debug  just returns **ECHO is off.**, which tells me it's either not finding the file or the for loop isn't returning the file date. Not sure why.

I've also tried minor changes to this just to double check environmental variable syntax:

```
FOR %%f IN (%myFile%) DO SET myFileDate=%%~ta
```

Returns **%ta**

And finally:

```
FOR %%f IN (%myFile%) DO SET myFileDate=%~ta
```

Which without the extra '%', just crashes the batch.

***I'm really at a loss at this point. So any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated!***

Comment: you can't temporarily map the unc path to a drive letter? most apps that bitch/whine about unc paths don't actually care if the files are remote network resources, they're just picky about only working on drive letters.

Comment: @Marc B - the drive is actually mapped, the problem becomes I run this batch systematically (via task scheduler). So when the system calls it, it runs at a level before mapped drive letters are actually 'applied' to the user system. If you know a work around I'd be more than willing to give it a try though.

Comment: have the batch map the drive itself?

Comment: Changed it to the drive path and received "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." (But if I copy-paste the path & name in explorer I get the file). Thoughts?

Comment: @TMY - The scheduled task still needs permissions to that UNC path. So if the task is set to only run when the user is logged in and that user has permissions to that path, then it will run just fine. But if you have the task set to run when a user is not logged in, then a username and password has to be supplied to the task that has permissions to that unc path.

Comment: @Squashman - I'm using the drive letter but get the error above "ERROR: No files found...".  I'm not using the task scheduler for testing, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.

Comment: @TMY - update your question with the exact code you are testing with. At this point I don't know which code base you are using and what your file path looks like.

Comment: I'm actually running both (I run the ForFiles line, followed by the For loop. I'm receiving the "No files found..." error from the `ForFiles` line of code

Comment: @TMY - well I can only guess at what your code looks like now after all your changes to it.  Is the error coming from the `FORFILES` command or the `FOR` command?  Pretty sure your `FOR` command will fail because you are not putting quotes around the variable.  File paths with spaces need to be quoted.

Comment: @TMY This code will fail `forfiles /p "%myPath%" /m %myFile% /c "GoTo OldFile" /d -6 ` not just because it does not support UNC paths but because `GOTO` is an internal command.  So you need to use cmd.exe with the internal command you want to run.  But it will still probably fail because I am pretty sure `GOTO` does not work in a FORFILES context.

Comment: @TMY Also, this code is failing because you are using the wrong `FOR` variable: `FOR %%f IN (%myFile%) DO SET myFileDate=%%~ta`.  It should be `%%~tf`.  My best coding practices always tells me to use uppercase characters for my `FOR` variables and lower case for the modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to both @Squashman and @MadsTheMan for the help. Luckily this batch *finally* is the piece of code that I can take to my boss to push switching over to *at least* using PowerShell!

Anyway, for those of you looking for the best way to get a UNC path file's modify date, here is what I've come up with.  Not very different than other threads (and a thanks goes out to Squashman for spotting my missing " " in the for loop).

```
set myFile=\\myUNCpath\myFileName.ext

FOR %%f IN ("%myFile%") DO SET myFileDate=%%~tf

::And if you'd like to try to do long winded calculations you can further break the dates down via...
set fileMonth=%myFileDate:~0,2%
set fileDay=%myFileDate:~3,2%
set fileYear=%myFileDate:~6,4%

set currentDate=%date%
set currentMonth=%currentDate:~4,2%
set currentDay=%currentDate:~7,2%
set currentYear=%currentDate:~10,4%
```

The plan was to then convert the strings to integers, and then use a switch-case block to determine if the variance between dates was acceptable... blah blah blah.

Long story short - if you are limited to batch (and not creating secondary files -- such as a csv or the temp file suggested by MadsTheMan) you're going to have a really long script on your hands that still might have flaws (like leap year, etc unless you're adding even MORE code), when you could just make the comparison calculation using one line of code in other programs.

Answer (score 1):

Using forfiles to a UNC path can be used using PushD

For just echoing the file older than x in UNC path, simply just use

```
PushD %myPath% &&(
forfiles -s -m %myFile% -d -6 -c "cmd /c echo /q @file 
 ) & PopD
```

Here is one way how to use goto if file older than x found in UNC path using your examples.

```
if not exist "C:\temp" mkdir C:\temp
if not exist "C:\temp\test.txt" echo.>"c:\temp\test.txt"
break>"c:\temp\test.txt"

set myPath=\\myUNCpath
set myFile=myFileName.csv

PushD %myPath% &&(
forfiles -s -m %myFile% -d -6 -c "cmd /c echo /q @file >> c:\temp\test.txt" 

 ) & PopD

for /f %%i in ("C:\temp\test.txt") do set size=%%~zi
if %size% gtr 0 goto next

:next
```